# How to align the first item left, and the second right in a row in react native?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I put two items (e.g. two buttons) in one row. I want to align the first item left, and align the second item right, which looks like:

[image]

How to achieve this in react native using flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found there're two easy ways to achieve this:

```js
// first way
<View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
<Button>B1</Button> // align left
<Button>B2</Button> // align right
</View>

// second way
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
<Button>B1</Button> // align left
<Button style={{marginLeft: "auto"}}>B2</Button> // align right
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

to do this, use `space-between`. If the container has a `width` larger than the 2 buttons, you'll see one on the left, one on the right

[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)